# Guarantee execution order of script tags in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iis

I have a page that contains multiple script-tags that reference .aspx-pages (in the same app and site).

As far as I know these are all called in order of appearance by the browser. However, it looks like when the calls arrive at the web server, the order of execution is no longer the same (usually).

Is there a way in ASP.NET (we are using version 4.5) to make sure the order of execution is always the same as how they appear in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The tags likely fire in order at the client. They may not arrive in order at the server. The browser may send requests on separate connections and order will not be respected. You may force one script tag to activate the next, and so on.

Comment: Thanks! But what I was trying to say was: Is there a way to make ASP.NET execute the .aspx-pages (as called by the script tags) in an order I decide?